# Class instance change another instance

Tags: java

The code is :

```
package classes;

public class Test {
    private static double mutationRate = 0.5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Population pop = new Population();
        pop.initialise();
        Population po = new Population();
        po.getIndividusList().add(pop.getFittest());
        po.getIndividusList().add(mutate(pop.getIndividusList().get(1)));
    }

    private static Chromosom mutate(Chromosom l) { // changer les couples d'interventions des parcs)
        // loop through genes
        Chromosom ch = new Chromosom();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
            ch.put(i, l.get(i));

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.size(); i++) {
            double alea = Math.random() * 13;
            int moisIntervention1 = (int) alea;

            Intervention interv1 = new Intervention(1, moisIntervention1);
            ch.get(i).modInterventions(ch.get(i).intervention2(interv1));
        }
        return ch;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I did not change the instance pop but when I change the other instance po, pop changes too.

Comment: As you populate `po` with the contents of `pop`, when you change `po`, `pop` still points at the same changed objects.

Comment: You need to actually copy the contents of pop into po... not point like the above comment

Comment: Excellent variable naming, though.

Comment: What does class `Population` look like? Are its member variables `static` (which means they are shared between all instances of `Population`)?

Comment: The problem is likely in your implementation of the class `Population`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's the exact duplicate of a closed question.

Comment: The class population don't have any variable static.

Answer (score 1):

java pass by value.

when you call this `mutate(pop.getIndividusList().get(1))`

you are sending pop's instance, so it will get change.

Supose `pop.getIndividusList().get(1)` return `String varibale` do this way

```
String var=pop.getIndividusList().get(1);
```

then call `mutate(var)`

Comment: so what can i do ? there is any solution to not sending pop's instance ? thanks

Comment: what pop.getIndividusList().get(1) return?
store it in some variable and then mutate(variableHavingValue)

Comment: what pop.getIndividusList().get(1) return an instance of another class. i do what you told me to do and i still have the same probleme. i did:      Chromosom var= what pop.getIndividusList().get(1)     then i call mutate(var)

Comment: pop.getIndividusList().get(1) implement hash table

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about whether I understood the problem, but I think that you mean that when you alter the items in Population `po`, the items in Population `pop` mirror those changes.

That is, indeed, the expected behavior of your code: to populate `po`, you are adding items from `pop` - `(pop.getFittest, pop.getList.get(1) )`.

But the individuals are, I believe, instances of objects, so add/remove and similar operations work with references to the objects, and not with copies of them. Therefore, as you have 2 references to the same obj, any change is mirrored.

IF you want to create a copy, you should add to `po` a new object with the same state, either by creating a constructor that takes another instance as parameter, implementing a copy method, or something similar.

It should be something like this:

```
    Population po = new Population();
    Individual fittest = pop.getFittest();
    Individual poCopy = new Individual();
    //ADD CODE HERE TO COPY ALL THE FIELDS FROM fittest TO poCopy
    //....

    po.getIndividusList().add(poCopy);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i try this methode but i still have the same problem