# Change the value of instance without changing the other instance

Tags: java

For those who had read my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242834/class-instance-change-another-instance), I think I found where the problem is. The problem is in the `mutate` method and especially in this instruction:

```
Chromosom ch=new Chromosom(); // Chromosom is a class who use hash table  
Chromosom k= new Chromosom(); // Class chromosom extends  hashmap <integer,parc>
k.initialise(); 
for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++) ch.put(i,k.get(i)); // in this instruction i think
```

And this is the constructor of Chromosom:

```
public Chromosom(){   // construct a blank chromosom
    super();
    this.identifiant = 0;
    NbEquipeExterne = 0;
    NbEquipeInterne = 0;
    CoutMinimal = 0;
    CoutMensuel = 0;
}
```

When I change the values of `ch`, the values of `k` change too?

How can I pass the `k`'s values to `ch`  by *copy* and not by *reference*?

Comment: You can clone the object you want to pass by copy at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Show us the constructor of `Chromosom()`. You're probably returning the same reference.

Comment: You can clone k.get(i) before ch.put() in case there is a possibility of updating same objects.

Comment: You should also tell us about the class you want to copy (parc?). Probably it is better to design it immutable so that it doesn't have to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [*Java is always pass-by-value.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) or rather *pass-by-copy-of-the-variable-value* not pass by reference. You might be changing objects of `Chromosom` with `k`  in the constructor.

Comment: I do what you ask me to do. In the first time, k have the same value as ch after changine. Now , in using yhe cinstructor, k change but not have the same value as ch.

Answer (score 0):

No danger, both `ch` and `k` are separate objects.

Furthermore you can do

```
ch.putAll(k);
```

which is a nice short-cut to remember.

***Caveat***

1. If the values of the maps are stateful objects (having mutable fields to contain some changing info), then changing that field would change the field of the simgle value object in both tables.

   ```
   BitSet bits = k.get(i);
   bits.set(3);
   // Now ch.get(i) being the same object, also has bit 3 set.
   ```
2. If a class has a `static` field, then that field is once per class, a single instance. So you could have in say Chromosome:

   ```
   static String copyright;

   Chromosome.copyright = "All rights reserved"; // Clearest style
   k.copyright = "All rights given to the community";
   ch.copyright = "MIT license";
   ```

   And you would have dealt with the same single variable, with vaklue "MIT license".

***About Java***

A nice design decision was made in java:

- If you pass a variable to a function/method, the object/value will be passed. It may never happen that the variable itself gets an other object/value. (Not the address of the variable is passed.) Java has pass-by-value, no pass-by-reference.

Comment: I use putAll, I do: ch.putAll(k) but i still have the same problem they have always the same value after changing. However, when i use a constructor to copy the value of k. the value of K change but diferent of value of ch. I don't want change the value of k, i wanted change just the value of ch.

Comment: Maybe do a regular expression search in files for `ch\s*=` and `k\s*=` (assigments). That would be only remaining explanation. `System.out.println(ch);` resp. with `k` would show whether they really are the same instance. Maybe there is another misconception. Would it be possible that you explain where it shows as same instance? Maybe it is a mixup, copied code without changing k to ch.  Or so.